# How to hide a row in RDLC when particular field value matches with some string value?

Tags: crystal-reports, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, dynamic-rdlc-generation

For Ex:In RDLC, I have a Grid with the following columns

period,

Quantity,

description etc..

I will get Period values as dates and one value as `"Avg"`, Now when My Period Value is "Avg", I want to hide that row from Grid in RDLC report.how can i do this?

I tried like below:

Row Visibility -> Show or Hide Based on Expression ->

(Fields!Period.Value = "Avg", True, False). But it is not working.

Please help me in this regard....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check actual values of Period field. Also, expression for Visibility in this case should start with equal sign and IIF (in case you didn't just copied it partially):

```
= IIF(Fields!Period.Value = "Avg", True, False)
```